# Windows 7 - can't uninstall application as admin

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, administrator

I'm trying to uninstall Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 from my Windows 7 machine. Logged in as administrator, when I attempt to uninstall I get a messagebox stating

"The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation."

Excuse me? No I haven't.

Immediately following, another messagebox displays:

"You do not have sufficient access to uninstall Microsoft Virtual PC 2007. Please contact your system administrator."

I didn't do anything unusual when installing or setting up the software. Just normal home use computer.

Any ideas on how to remove this software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Virtual PC may be holding some resources that prevents the uninstall. Reboot into Safe Mode and try the uninstall again.

This [page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode) describes how to boot into safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Virtual Server, this happens when Application Information service gets someway stuck or stopped.

Rebooting is enough to fix it.